# Why is my Xcode debugging session stopping

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3 and trying to debug a Core Data problem I'm having with inserting some default data into the persistent store. I'm learning from a  Core Data book and in a little above my head

This function is checking to see if we even need to import the default data (trust me, we do) and then will set it up if necessary:

```
func checkIfDefaultDataNeedsSetup (url:NSURL, type:String) {
        if isDefaultDataAlreadySetupForStoreWithURL(url, type: type) == false {

            if let lift = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Lift", inManagedObjectContext: CDHelper.shared.context) { /*breakpoint*/ 1

                // not returning here 
                let newLiftEvent = Lift(entity: lift, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: CDHelper.shared.context)

                newLiftEvent.uid = 0
                newLiftEvent.liftName = "Back Squat"

                CDHelper.saveSharedContext()

            }  else {
            // skip setup
            }
            return
        }
```

At breakpoint1 it calls CDHelper.shared.context (the inManagedObjectContext argument) where I have it stopping at breakpoints 2 and 3:

```
private let _sharedCDHelper = CDHelper() /* breakpoint 3 */
class CDHelper : NSObject  {

// MARK: - SHARED INSTANCE
class var shared : CDHelper {
    return _sharedCDHelper /* breakpoint 2 */
}
```

When stopped at breakpoint 3, as soon as I click Step Into I get this:

[image]

I would expect it to return to the next line after breakpoint 1 where it went off to get `CDHelper.shared.context` but it doesn't. Xcode and Simulator aren't hung up or anything. It just gets to this point and stays there as if its waiting for something.

I'm guessing this optional binding `if let lift = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Lift", inManagedObjectContext: CDHelper.shared.context)` isn't getting assigned so it's not going into the method. But I'm as certain as I can be that the Lift entity is in the managedObjectContext. I see it in my `.xcdatamodeld`, I've looked in the db using DB for SQLite, and I've even deleted the data model and recreated it. I've also ensured that I'm using just the `.MainQueueConcurrencyType`.

Is there an obvious problem that anyone can see or are there other things I should look for? Maybe something else I can do to ensure the `Lift` entity is in the managed object context like I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing this optional binding `if let lift = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Lift", inManagedObjectContext: CDHelper.shared.context)` isn't getting assigned

Why guess? Remove or disable all breakpoints and put a breakpoint on that line. Now run the app. When we pause at that breakpoint, step over. Now look to see where you are.